# Why nitration of biphenyl gives 2­-nitrobiphenyl as major product?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In nitration reaction of biphenyl with nitric acid, 2­-nitrobiphenyl was the predominant product. nitration is directed to o,p positions, but why o position is more preferred? and why nitration stops at this level? I mean why don't we get 2,4-dinitrobiphenyl?

Answer (score 2):

There are really two parts to this question.  1)  Why is the Attack preferentially at the 2 position?  2)  Why does only a single nitro group get incorporated?

1)  We can think of the substrate as a substituted benzene where the substituent, the second phenyl group, contributes pi electrons by resonance.  That makes it an ortho/para director.  Then why is ortho preferred over para to give 2-nitrobiphenyl?

Draw the resonance contributions in both cases.  If you are careful, the ortho attack produces one more contribution:  the proton on the temporarily saturated C-2 can overlap with the pi electron ring on the second phenyl group, effectively becoming part of that aromatic ring.  The ortho attack is thereby enhanced by providing a lower energy transition state.

2)  Once you have a nitro group on one ring, that ring is deactivated directly and the other is also deactivated by conjugation.  Further nitration is thereby more difficult.  We may get it after all, more likely on the ring that did not get the first nitro group, under stronger conditions.  Biphenyl is by no means unique, any polynitration of an aromatic substrate faces similar problems.

Comment: So if we reduce the nitro group to amino group, that will activate both phenyl rings (which have nitro group and the other one). Then further nitration will be possible. The question her is what are the favorite positions for further nitration?Is nitration going to proceed in the same ring of amino group or in the other ring? I think nitration will proceed on o,p positions but which of them is more preferred?

Comment: This wasn't included in your original question. You may ask this as a different question.